# Building a Shift Dictionary and Applying Shift for Caesar cipher

Tags: python, python-2.7

This question is from a course that I am working on.
I have tried answering this question but I have not made any headway.
Please respond with code that will solve this problem.
The problem is present below.

Problem:
The 'Message' class contains methods that could be used to apply a cipher to a string, either to encrypt or to decrypt a message (since for Caesar codes this is the same action).

In the next two questions, you will fill in the methods of the Message class found in ps6.py according to the specifications in the docstrings. The methods in the Message class already filled in are:

`__init__(self, text)`

The getter method `get_message_text(self)`

The getter method `get_valid_words(self)`, notice that this one returns a copy of `self.valid_words` to prevent someone from mutating the original list.

In this problem, you will fill in two methods:

Fill in the `build_shift_dict(self, shift)` method of the `Message` class. Be sure that your dictionary includes both lower and upper case letters, but that the shifted character for a lower case letter and its uppercase version are lower and upper case instances of the same letter. What this means is that if the original letter is "a" and its shifted value is "c", the letter "A" should shift to the letter "C".

If you are unfamiliar with the ordering or characters of the English alphabet, we will be following the letter ordering displayed by string.ascii_lowercase and string.ascii_uppercase:

```
>>> import string
>>> print string.ascii_lowercase
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>>> print string.ascii_uppercase
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

A reminder from the introduction page - characters such as the space character, commas, periods, exclamation points, etc will not be encrypted by this cipher - basically, all the characters within string.punctuation, plus the space (' ') and all numerical characters (0 - 9) found in 'string.digits'.

Fill in the `apply_shift(self, shift)` method of the `Message` class. You may find it easier to use `build_shift_dict(self, shift)`. Remember that spaces and punctuation should not be changed by the cipher.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: It's unlikely that anyone will answer a question asking for code for your homework. Please provide your steps to solve it or ask a new question if you are stuck somewhere and have a specific problem. For more information about "How to ask a question" please check the [SO help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: All right, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
def build_shift_dict(self, shift):
    dict1 = {}
    str1 = string.ascii_uppercase
    for s in str1:
        if (ord(s)+shift-65) < 26 :
             dict1[s] = chr(ord(s)+shift)
        elif (ord(s)+shift-65) >= 26 :
             dict1[s] = chr(ord(s)+shift-26)

    str1 = string.ascii_lowercase
    for s in str1:
        if (ord(s)+shift-97) < 26 :
             dict1[s] = chr(ord(s)+shift)
        elif (ord(s)+shift-97) >= 26 :
             dict1[s] = chr(ord(s)+shift-26)

    return dict1    

def apply_shift(self, shift):
    msg = self.get_message_text()
    newMsg = ""
    dict1 = self.build_shift_dict(shift)
    for i in range(len(msg)):
        if dict1.has_key(msg[i]):
            newMsg += dict1.get(msg[i])
        else:
            newMsg += msg[i]
    return newMsg
```